# How do I style the a Vuetify v-data-table's scroll-bar?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using a `Vuetify` `v-data-table` and I want to customize the the data-table's scroll-bar,
how can I do that?
right now it is looking like this:

[image]

is there a way to style it to my liking?

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal
I tried using :
`::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }`
inside the components style tag but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

If you need a styled scrollbar only for the table in the component, you can try this out.

```
<style scoped>
::v-deep .v-data-table .v-data-table__wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width:10px;
}
</style>
```